# Android-Get image from customListview and display the same in a imageview,without using database

Tags: java, android

I have customListview with images and text.I am accessing text from database and images are stored as an array.When I click on a row of listview,I want the image corresponding to that row image to display in an imageview of another activity.I dont know how to access the selected image.I donot want to store image in database.

**product_display.java**

```
public class product_display extends Activity {


ListView prd_list;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.product_dispay);
    prd_list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    DataBaseHandler dbh = new DataBaseHandler(this);
     Intent in=getIntent();
     Bundle bundle=in.getExtras();
     final String list=bundle.getString("key");
     SQLiteDatabase db = dbh.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cr = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM product", null);
    final String[] pname = new String[cr.getCount()];
    String[] price = new String[cr.getCount()];

    int i = 0;
    while(cr.moveToNext())
    {
        String name = cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex("pname"));
        String prprice = cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex("pprice"));

        pname[i] = name;
        price[i] = prprice;
        i++;
    }

    ListAdapter adapter = new ListAdapter(this, pname, price);
    prd_list.setAdapter(adapter);

    prd_list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String nme = pname[arg2];   
   //       passing username from loginpage
            Bundle bun = new Bundle();
            bun.putString("key",list);
  //        passing product name as bundle

            Bundle bn = new Bundle();
            bn.putString("name",nme);
            Intent in = new Intent(product_display.this, Product_Details.class);
            in.putExtras(bun);
            in.putExtras(bn);
            startActivity(in);
            }
    });



}

}
```

**ListAdapter.java**

```
public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private final String[] pname;
private final String[] price;
Integer [] pmge ={R.drawable.candle1,R.drawable.candl3,
        R.drawable.candl4,R.drawable.candl5,R.drawable.candl6,
        R.drawable.lawn,R.drawable.sglc10,R.drawable.senson,R.drawable.thejus6669};
private Context mcontext;
    public ListAdapter(Context c,String[] pname,String[] price){
    mcontext=c;
    this.pname=pname;
    this.price=price;
}

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return pname.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         View List;
         LayoutInflater mLayoutinflater=(LayoutInflater) mcontext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
         if(convertView==null){
         List=new View(mcontext);

         List=mLayoutinflater.inflate(R.layout.mylist, parent, false);
         }
         else{
         List = (View)convertView;
         }

         TextView textView1 = (TextView)List.findViewById(R.id.pr_name);
         TextView textView2 = (TextView)List.findViewById(R.id.pr_price);
         ImageView imageview= (ImageView)List.findViewById(R.id.pr_img);
         textView1.setText(pname[position].toString());
         textView2.setText("Rs "+price[position] +" /-");
         imageview.setImageResource(pmge[position]);
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         return List;

    }

}
```

**product_Details.java**

```
public class Product_Details extends Activity{

TextView name,price,specification,feature;
String nme;
SQLiteDatabase mydb;
String pname;
String prprice;
String pspec;
String pfeature;
Button add2cart,by_nw;
ImageView image;
ImageButton imgbtn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.product_dtls);
    image=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.pr_img);
    name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtPr_name);
    price = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtprice);
    specification=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtPr_spec);
    feature=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtPr_feature);
    imgbtn=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.cartimg);
    add2cart=(Button)findViewById(R.id.add2cart);
    by_nw=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buy_nw);
    DataBaseHandler dbh = new DataBaseHandler(this);
     SQLiteDatabase db = dbh.getWritableDatabase();
    Intent in = getIntent();
    Bundle bn = in.getExtras();
    Bundle bun=in.getExtras();
    final String dtl=bun.getString("key");
    nme = bn.getString("name");

    while(cr.moveToNext())
    {
        String name = cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex("pname"));
        String pr1price = cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex("pprice"));
        String prspc=cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex("pspec"));
        String prfeature=cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex("pfeature"));
        pname = name;
        prprice = pr1price;
        pspec=prspc;
        pfeature=prfeature;
    }
    name.setText(pname);
    price.setText("Rs " +prprice + "/-");
    specification.setText(pspec);
    feature.setText(pfeature);


    add2cart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            boolean incart=false;
            String nm=name.getText().toString();
            mydb=Product_Details.this.openOrCreateDatabase("addcart", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
            mydb.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS add2cart(usr TEXT,img BLOB,pnme TEXT,prate NUMERIC,pqty NUMERIC,ptotl NUMERIC)");
            Cursor cur=mydb.rawQuery("select * from add2cart where pnme='"+nm+"' AND usr='"+dtl+"'",null);

            if (cur.moveToFirst()){
                String prdname=cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("pnme"));

                if (nm.equals(prdname)){
                    add2cart.setText("Already in Cart");
                    incart=true;
                }
            }

            if(incart==false){
                mydb.execSQL("INSERT INTO add2cart (usr,pnme,prate)VALUES('"+dtl+"','"+nm+"','"+prprice+"')");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"added to cart",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        }
    });
}
}
```

**EDITED CODE**

```
@Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    clas = (Integer)getListAdapter().getItem(arg2);
    Intent in = new Intent(product_display.this, Product_Details.class);
    in.putExtra("num", clas);
    startActivity(in);

}
```

And I get the value by

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
     int imgvalue = extras.getInt("num");
```

But How to set image to my image view,if image is my image view

```
image.set ???
```

Answer (score 2):

**Click on Listview**

```
// Capture ListView item click
    itemVie.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
resulta = data.get(position);
Intent intent = new Intent(context, SecondActivity.class);

intent.putExtra("albname", resulta.get(Portfolio.TAG_TITLE));
intent.putExtra("portimages",resulta.get(Portfolio.TAG_IMAGE));
context.startActivity(intent);



}
});
```

Comment: @paypaluser itemVie and data are the adapters parameters. Anything else?

Comment: I am new to adapter concept.Can you edit the above part of code using variables I used in my code instead of itemVie and data.So that I can understand

Answer (score 0):

If your images are inside an array then make sure that the indexing of the array matches that of the data you taking from the database (you can do this by converting the cursor to a list before you pass it to the adapter) then in the getview of your adapter you get the image by this line of code :

//I assume that you've done what I     told you. 
  //position is the nth item in the list and item is nth object(model) in the list you got from the database. V is the current view you are returning

V.setTag(imageArray[position] );

This V will be passed to you as argument in the onListItemClick metthod

Get the image by this line of code

//V is the passed view argument

Bitmap image =V.getTag();

Comment: OnListItemClick() is not getting invoked in my code.What to do.?

Answer (score 0):

You can get selected row item object from `ListView` by calling `getItem` method of Adapter using `getListAdapter`  like this

```
prd_list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {     
      Integer class = (Integer)getListAdapter().getItem(arg2);
      // pass this integer to the another activity and display there.
}
```

Comment: implements like this for your activity public class YourClass extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener

Comment: please give a look at my EDITED CODE...What should I do ?